# Kleene normal form theorem for r.e. relations proven in arithmetical theories

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, reverse-math, theories-of-arithmetic, recursively-enumerable

After reading the relevant chapters of *Classical Recursion Theory* (freely available from [here](http://www.piergiorgioodifreddi.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/CRT1.pdf)), I have the following questions concerning Theorem II.1.10 (Normal form theorem) and Theorem IV.1.9 (Enumeration theorem):

- What arithmetical theory based on first-order logic is able to prove the equivalence claimed in the statement of Theorem II.1.10 (and its counterpart IV.1.9, for $\Sigma^{0}_{n}$ formulas) (Something stronger that Robinson's $\mathbf{Q}$, I guess);
- What arithmetical theory based on first-order logic is able to prove the *universal closure* of the equivalence claimed in the statement of Theorem II.1.10 (and its counterpart IV.1.9, for $\Sigma^{0}_{n}$ formulas)?

Even if you don't have precise answers, useful references would be appreciated too.

Comment: The problem here is not so much with *proving* things, but *defining* them. The definition of computability using partial recursive function needs the totality of insanely fast-growing functions so that closure under primitive recursion makes sense. In contrast, if you use a sane definition of computability (i.e., Turing machines), then basic results such as the normal form theorem, s-n-m theorem, etc. can be proved in weak fragments of bounded arithmetic, such as PV (the basic theory of polynomial-time functions).

Answer (score 4):

The usual formal systems in which one can carry out basic recursion-theoretic constructions and theorems such as the ones you are asking about are $\mathrm{I}\Sigma_1$ (a fragment of $\mathrm{PA}$ in which the induction scheme is limited to $\Sigma_1$-formulas) and its counterpart $\mathrm{RCA_0}$ (a subsystem of second order arithmetic).  The latter is a conservative extension of the former (i.e., any purely arithmetical statement is provable in the latter iff it provable in the former).

A good reference for the former is Chapter I of the book "Meta-mathematics of First-Order Arithmetic" by Petr Hájek and Pavel Pudlák (a free copy of which can be found [here](https://projecteuclid.org/eBooks/perspectives-in-logic/Metamathematics-of-First-Order-Arithmetic/toc/pl/1235421926)), and for the latter, the standard reference is Stephen Simpson's "Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic".

A related MO question-and-answer is [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366177/what-subsystem-of-second-order-arithmetic-is-needed-for-the-recursion-theorem) about formalizing Kleene's recursion theorem.

Finally: There are more spartan formal systems for handling the basics of computability/recursion theory, as pointed out by Emil Jeřábek in his comment to the question.